# Batch file is opening a cmd window for a moment and then closing it

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to run a simple batch file on Windows 7 which contains only:

```
cd\
```

For some reason it is just opening a `cmd.exe` screen for a flash and then closing it.

I tried running another batch file that worked for my friend in his computer and the same thing happend.

Any ideas why?

Comment: what happens if you only open cmd.exe without running any batch file? [Check if there's any startup command in cmd](https://superuser.com/q/302194/241386)

Comment: I'm going to assume that it changed to the root directory of the current drive as asked, then closed, because that's exactly what the script asks of it. If you want it to not immediately close, add any one of the following as a second line in the batch file: `Pause`, `Timeout -1` or `Timeout 5`. Then feedback what happened and if you still have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the advice offered in the comment area, if you want to open a `cmd.exe` window, from a batch file, and with a specific drive or path as 'current' and keep it open, then your batch file content may look a little like this:

```bat
@Start /B /D "/" "Cmd /K"
```

In this example your required current working directory is entered in the doublequoted string following `Start`'s `/D` option. To see the options `/B` and `/D` and its other available options, take a look at the usage information for the `Start` command, by entering `Start /?` in a Command Prompt window. *If your batch file was to contain more commands other than that you've shown, you will probably dsiscover that the `/B` option is not wanted*.

To see the usage information for `cmd.exe`, *(and what its `/K` option does)*, you can similarly enter `Cmd /?` at the Command Prompt too. *Depending if you have any set, it may also be prudent to disable any AutoRun commands by including the `/D` option.*

Please also note that above I have used `Cmd`, which is an abbreviation for `cmd.exe`. *This abbreviation works only if you have an executable file, determined as one which has an extension listed under the system variable, `%PATHEXT%`, in either the current working directory, the `Windows` directory (`%SystemRoot%`), the `Windows\System32` directory (`%SystemRoot%\system32`), listed under the system variable `%Path%`, or one listed in the registry under the `…\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` or `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\` keys). If your executable file does not exist in any of those, you'd need to enter its full, or relative (to the current working directory), path instead.*

Answer (score 0):

Batch files opened from explorer automatically closes after finishing all the commands given.
If your batch file does not contain anything that takes more than a second to execute then only flashes up and closes.

The command `cd\` does changing the current directory **in the command line** to the root directory.

To use this file (and see what it does) open up a console window and type in the file name with it's path.*To open a command line in the current directory hold shift and right click while no file is selected and click "open console window here" button.*

---

Alternatively you can add a `pause` command and the flashing ends.

---

To open an explorer window wherever you point `cd` use this code:

```
cd path
explorer .
```

---

Hope this helps